# How to view your translated site?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-i18n

I am trying to view my site in japanese. I have create the translations and compiled them with compilemessages.

In my urls.py I have

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    #...
)
```

Settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

#Used for translations
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('jp', gettext('Japanese')),    
)
```

But when I try to access a url with /jp/ at the start I get that there is only /en/

Using the URLconf defined in PLP.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^en/
```

The current URL, jp/accounts/login, didn't match any of these.

I am using dbgettext so I also have my database content translated in my messages.

But how can I display it

```
   {% trans "Question:" %}{% trans {{question.question}} %}<br>
```

Could not parse the remainder: '{{question.question}}' from '{{question.question}}'

## EDIT

Thanks Ngenator!

My other issue was that Japanese is 'ja' not 'jp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the [{% trans %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag) tag takes a variable directly, so you don't need those extra braces, just

```
{% trans "Question:" %}{% trans question.question %}<br>
```

or using the [{% blocktrans %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) tag

```
{% blocktrans %}Question: {{ question.question }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

should work. I'm not sure about the url issues though.